# Cancelling a Prepaid Contract (US) from Germany

Tags: usa, cellphones, pre-pay

I have a problem: For my holiday in the US I got a prepaid SIM card from AT&T. In the store I explicitly said I wanted it for only one month and the saleswoman explicitly said they won't charge me anything after that. Well, now I did get charged another month, because they apparently forgot to cancel autopay. Following the homepage, I wanted to login into my account, but I need to enter a 4 digit PIN that I get via SMS. But I don't get any carrier here in Germany on the AT&T SIM card, so I can't receive any SMS.

What can I do now? I cannot find a contact email anywhere, for costumer chat I would need a login. They have my email, but if they ever sent one, it must have gotten into my spam filter (I did not think I'd need anything from AT&T).

My credit card provider can neither block AT&T from charging me, nor reverse the charge.

Can you guys help me find a way to cancel my contract? If possible I want to avoid paying the money to call the hotline from Germany.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Skype, google voice, or another voip app to call the customer service number in the United States. It’ll be a free (or very low-cost) call.

Comment: Very good tip! I didn't even think of using Skype. I just called them and was able to verify my account without access to the pass code that I was supposed to get via SMS. After confirming when the last payment was charged they disabled the automatic payment.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to cancel the contract is to call them personally from Germany and provide all the related info about your self. There is no any effective way to cancel such a thing rather than calling the hotline.